# Can't convert Frozen Inference Graph to .tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite, toco

I am new to the object detection API and TensorFlow in general. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjiBbChYRDw&t=1248s) tutorial and in the end I produced a `frozen_inference_graph.pb`. I want to run this object detection model on my phone, which in my understanding requires me to convert it to .tflite (please lmk if this doesn't make any sense).

When I tried to convert it using this standard code here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
graph = 'pathtomygraph'
input_arrays = ['image_tensor']
output_arrays = ['all_class_predictions_with_background']


converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(graph, input_arrays, output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

It throws an error, saying:

> ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor
>   'image_tensor' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'

This is a common error I found on the internet, and after searching through many threads, I tried to give an extra parameter to the code:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
        graph, input_arrays, output_arrays,input_shapes={"image_tensor":[1,600,600,3]})
```

Now it looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
graph = 'pathtomygraph'
input_arrays = ['image_tensor']
output_arrays = ['all_class_predictions_with_background']


converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
        graph, input_arrays, output_arrays,input_shapes={"image_tensor":[1,600,600,3]})
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

This **works** at first, but throws another error at the end, saying:

> Check failed: array.data_type == array.final_data_type Array
>   "image_tensor" has mis-matching actual and final data types
>   (data_type=uint8, final_data_type=float). Fatal Error: Aborted

I understand that my input tensor has the data type of uint8 and this causes a mismatch, I guess. My question would be, is this the correct way to approach things? (I want to run my model on my phone). If it is, how do I then fix the error? :/

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change your model input (the `image_tensor` placeholder) to have data type `tf.float32`.